# Создать блок, заголовок?

Tags: css, html

Как добавить сюда либо меню либо баннер или текстовый заголовок?

[image: Выделенная область]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("../img/1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  height: 560px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.card:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.card .info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card .info h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.card .info p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.card .info button {
  padding: 0.6rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.card .info button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>11111</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="http://site.ru/">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
        <div class="info">
          <h1>1111</h1>
          <p>1111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://site.ru/">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
        <div class="info">
          <h1>1111</h1>
          <p>1111</p>
          <p>1111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://site.ru/">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
        <div class="info">
          <h1>1111</h1>
          <p>1111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://site.ru/">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
        <div class="info">
          <h1>1111</h1>
          <p>1111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://site.ru/">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
        <div class="info">
          <h1>1111</h1>
          <p>1111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(../img/1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  height: 560px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.card:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.card .info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card .info h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.card .info p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.card .info button {
  padding: 0.6rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.card .info button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Banner || title</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="http://site.ru/">
    <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
      <div class="info">
        <h1>1111</h1>
        <p>1111</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://site.ru/">
    <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
      <div class="info">
        <h1>1111</h1>
        <p>1111</p>
        <p>1111</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://site.ru/">
    <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
      <div class="info">
        <h1>1111</h1>
        <p>1111</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://site.ru/">
    <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
      <div class="info">
        <h1>1111</h1>
        <p>1111</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://site.ru/">
    <div class="card"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477666250292-1419fac4c25c?auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=667&amp;q=80&amp;ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" />
      <div class="info">
        <h1>1111</h1>
        <p>1111</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: .wrapper (блок с гридами) стал выше, изначально был по центру страницы, как поправить?

Comment: @АлександрКаракозов, обновил.